# Ways to speed up a simpletest?

Tags: 7, testing

I'm trying to speed up my test. 
I have to use simpletest_clone.
I've read something like "copy the database to memory" but i did some research and didn't found how.
Aaand if i want to do more than one test with the same database there is somehow a thing that let you use the same database cloned for the first case i tested to be still loaded to run the next test case?
because if i want to run 4 or 5 test case using simpletest_clone it may take years if i let it clone and drop the database for every case

Answer (score 3):

There are few ways of speeding up the Simpletests:

- Consider upgrading your PHP to >5.5 with cache benefits of [OPCache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php).
- For PHP <=5.5 try to implement PHP caches such as [XCache](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/), [APC](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC), [eAccelerator](http://eaccelerator.net/).
- Install and configure memcached.
- Patch your Simpletest to exclude testing of disabled modules.

  See: [Tests of disabled modules shouldn't be parsed](https://www.drupal.org/node/1592668), [Strengthen tests by not autoregistering non-test namespaces of disabled modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2006476)
- Use [SimpleTest Clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/simpletest_clone)

  (consider patching the module to [exclude some big tables while cloning](https://www.drupal.org/node/1784474)).
- Optimize your MySQL instance e.g. via [MySQLTuner-perl](http://mysqltuner.com/).
- For sites that have lots of slow queries, disk access is often the bottleneck. [So speed up by moving MySQL temporary directory to tmpfs.](http://2bits.com/articles/reduce-your-servers-resource-usage-moving-mysql-temporary-directory-ram-disk.html), [How to setup mysql on tmpfs?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20649/how-to-setup-mysql-on-tmpfs)
- Test only specific Simpletests groups that you need.

Other option to consider:

- Try to identify the bottleneck and upgrade your hardware.
- Break down simpletests into groups and run on separate machines.
- Forget about the speed by integrating Simpletests with Continuous integration (CI) such as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), [Travis CI](http://www.travis-ci.org), AWS, etc.
- Use alternative test frameworks (e.g. PHPUnit), see: [[meta] Replace the testing framework with PHPUnit and possibly rewrite Simpletest](https://www.drupal.org/node/1567500).

Use alternatives:

- [Behat](http://docs.behat.org/) (recommended)
- [PHPUnit](https://www.drupal.org/phpunit) (which has been added to Drupal 8)
- [Selenium web driver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) or [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) (which is slow as well:)